# getopts with double colons for optional values

Tags: bash, getopts

Does getopts not accept optional arguments for an option using double colons (e.g. using shortopts="t::")?

Comment: For multi-word arguments, use quotes: `./script.sh -t "three word argument"` and remember that it is then one string with spaces in variable `OPTARG` that might need splitting depending on your use case.

Comment: `getopt` [does](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/parse-command-line-arguments-using-getopt#:~:text=Option%20string%20for%20short%20options&text=Each%20single%20character%20stands%20for,an%20optional%20argument%20or%20value.); `getopts` with an `s` does not. Beware options with *optional* arguments - how will the system decide whether a following argument is the optional value, or a new, separate argument? That's probably why `getopts` skipped it. I consider it a bug, not a feature.

Comment: @PaulHodges, the way the various `getopt()` implementations treat optional option-args is by taking everything after the option character in the same command line argument as the option-arg. So if `-a` takes an optional option-arg, `-abc` is `-a` with the opt-arg `bc`, while `-a bc` is `-a` without an opt-arg (or with the empty string), plus `bc` as a regular non-option argument. That gives a well-defined result and allows passing arbitrary strings as optional opt-args, but annoyingly different from how mandatory opt-args work, with both `-abc` and `-a bc` meaning `-a` with the opt-arg `bc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Bash's `getopts` doesn't support optional option-arguments.

There's nothing in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) to indicate that it would, it only says

> if a character is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument, which should be separated from it by whitespace.